# URL-forwarding to download a file: wget only downloads the index.html

Tags: download, wget, redirect

From time to time I have to download a specific file from a website with `wget`. The URL is very long, so I created a free .tk-domain that forwards to the file. If I use my new .tk-URL in my browser, it downloads the file as I want it but on my VPS on Ubuntu, it only downloads the index.html file if I use `wget`. I've two forwarding options on Dot.TK

- Frame (Cloaking)
- Redirect (HTTP 301 Forwarding)

Which option should I use and is there a way to get the file instead of the index.html?

Answer (score 1):

If you use a 301, `wget` should be able to download the file. You can also use `curl -LO <URL>` with the 301.

Comment: I don't know how long the change from `Frame (cloaking)` to `Redirect 301` may take at Dot.TK but for now it doesn't work with `wget` - it still downloads the index.html file. `curl -LO <myURL>` doesn't work neither. I get the error `curl: Remote file name has no length!`. I want to add that my TK-domain is http and the file-URL is HTTPS, but I think, that doesn't matter?

Comment: The HTTPS change shouldn't matter. I would really have to know the URL to debug it further, as both `wget` and `curl` should have no issue retrieving something from a URL after a 301.

Comment: It's `lisktest.tk` and redirects to `https://downloads.lisk.io/lisk/test/installLisk.sh`

Comment: Your `index.html` file being downloaded is the `installLisk.sh` file (open it up and check). The `-O` option in `curl` tries to figure out what to call the local file using the URL, and your setup doesn't make that possible, hence the file name of no length. Instead use either `wget -O installLisk.sh lisktest.tk` or `curl -Lo installLisk.sh lisktest.tk`. Both of those options specify the local file name.

Comment: Thx. My goal was that I have to remember and write as less as possible. If there is something else, I could do, let me know.

Comment: If you're after the shortest possible route you could write a bash alias. At the bottom of the `~/.bashrc` file, add `alias downloadLisk='wget -O installLisk.sh https://downloads.lisk.io/lisk/test/installLisk.sh'`. Then just type `downloadLisk` anywhere and it will download the file to the current directory. However, you might want to consider _why_ you're using this command so often and find a more permanent solution. This is also getting a bit far from the topic of your question.

Comment: I need the command to update the client. Nothing I can do. But thanks for the bash command. This way I can trash my TK-Doman, haha. Because now the URL length doesn't matter anymore. :)